# Lookup File name using values from Column and Paste Link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets document where I have names listed in Column D. I want to insert the PDF link of each file from a specific folder into Column G, ensuring that the PDF file name exactly matches the corresponding name in Column D. To accomplish this, I would like to use Google Sheets' app script functionality.

I have below code which runs fine but do not paste the output.

```
function pastePDFLinks() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // Replace "Sheet2" with your sheet name
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID"); // Replace "your_folder_id" with the ID of your folder

  var namesColumn = sheet.getRange("D2:D" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); // Assuming the names are in column D
  var pdfFiles = folder.getFilesByType("application/pdf");

  while (pdfFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = pdfFiles.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();

    for (var i = 0; i < namesColumn.length; i++) {
      var name = namesColumn[i][0];
      if (name === fileName) { // Perform an exact match comparison
        var pdfLink = file.getUrl();
        sheet.getRange("H" + (i + 2)).setValue(pdfLink); // Assuming the PDF links should be pasted in column H starting from row 2
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76517152/17926478) answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue, I had just the name of the PDF files without the `.pdf`. Like this:

[image]

After running the script, the links were not added to the sheet.

I added a `Logger.log(name + "=>" + fileName)` to the code, and I noticed that it is comparing the name with the name + .pdf.

[image: logger]

To fix this issue, you have 2 options:

**Option 1:**

Replace the if statement from:

```
if (name === fileName)
```

To:

```
if (name + ".pdf"  === fileName)
```

**Option 2:**

Rename the file's name inside the Google Sheet to `name+.pdf`. Like this:

[image: rename sheet]

Lastly, I created another version of the code that doesn't compare each file found with the names on the cell, in case the first 2 options do not solved the issue, you can use it as a workaround. Here is a sample:

```
function pastePDFLinks() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");
  let namesColumn = sheet.getRange("D2:D").getValues().flat();

  // Filter the data and removes empty values
  namesColumn = namesColumn.filter((element) => { return (element !== '') });
  
  for (let i = 0; i < namesColumn.length; i++) {
    // New variable with the name of the file
    let file_name = namesColumn[i]

    //Search the file by the specific name
    let search_file = folder.getFilesByName(file_name + '.pdf')
    while (search_file.hasNext()) {
      let file = search_file.next();

      //get the URL of the file 
      let file_url = file.getUrl()

      // sent the value of the URL
      sheet.getRange("H" + (i + 2)).setValue(file_url)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Giselle Valladares to keep you in wait, for the output. It is exactly what i want thank you. But can you please make it more fast to run it on large datset.